# Is an expression including array subscripting can be an identifier?

Tags: c, syntax, declaration, identifier

```
int a[2][4] = {........};
```

In the code above, `a` is an identifier of array type. But I'm curious whether `a[2]`, which is an array of 4 int elements, is also an identifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a[2]` is not an identifier.

The definition of identifiers in [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.4.2 is

> ```
> identifier:
>     identifier-nondigit
>     identifier identifier-nondigit
>     identifier digit
>
> identifier-nondigit:
>     nondigit
>     universal-character-name
>     other implementation-defined characters
>
> nondigit: one of
>     _ a b c d e f g h i j k l m
>       n o p q r s t u v w x y z
>       A B C D E F G H I J K L M
>       N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>
> digit: one of
>     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> ```

I don't think `[` and `]` are included in the "implementation-defined characters" for typical C compilers because they are used as array subscripting operator (N1570 6.5.2.1)

Answer (score 2):

No. Identifier is for example the name of a variable or a function. As @WhozCraig wrote in comment it's not only variable or function. The term comes from syntax parsers:

```
function ::= identifier '(' parameter ( ',' parameters )* ')'
```

In the example `a[2][4]` the `a` is an identifier and a value. Also `a[2]` and `a[2][4]` both are values, but not identifiers. They all also are l-values, i.e. you can write `a`, `a[2]`, and `a[2][4]` left of assign sign `=`:

```
a[2][4] = 100;
```

Comment: Note: The language standard does not restrict the term *identifier* to only functions and variables. Per §6.2.1, "An identifier can denote an object; a function; a tag or a member of a structure, union, or enumeration; a typedef name; a label name; a macro name; or a macro parameter."

Comment: @WhozCraig Corrected the answer.

Comment: They are not r-values but lvalues (objects with memory space allocated) and *can be converted to rvalues*.

Answer (score 2):

No, "identifier" strictly refers to a name built of alphanumeric and underscore characters.

However, `a`, `a[2]`, and `a[2][4]` are all *declarators* here.

Comment: Yes, inside the declaration, they are declarators. After the declaration, `a`, `a[i]` (where 0 ≤ `i` < 2), and `a[i][j]` (where 0 ≤ `i` < 2, 0 ≤ `j` < 4) are all *lvalues*, but only `a[i][j]` is a *modifiable lvalue*.

Answer (score 2):

`a[2]` is a postfix expression that is built from the primary expression identifier `a` and the subscript operator [].

If to consider the declaration alone

```
int a[2][4];
```

then this declaration declares identifier `a` as having type `int[2][4]`.

You could separate the identifier from other elements in the declaration using a typedef. For example

```
typedef int T[2][4];

T a;
```

Now it is more clear what is the identifier. Thus `a` is an identifier that has type `T` that in turn is equivalent to `int[2][4]`.

In the C grammar there is also such a notion as declarator. For example an identifier is a declarator. In the declaration below I enclosed all declarators in parentheses.

```
int ( ( ( a )[2] )[4] );
```

It is a valid declaration though looks confusing.:) That is in this declaration `a`, `a[2]` and `a[2][4]` are declarators that are built starting from the identifier `a`.

Comment: `a[2]` as used in the sample code is not syntactically an expression.

Comment: @aschepler I have appended my post that it would be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

No, `a[2]` is an element of an array *object*. Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.2.1/2, *Array subscripting*

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets `[]` is a subscripted
>   designation of an element of an array object.

To add, from §6.4.2.1, *Identifiers*

> An identifier is a sequence of nondigit characters (including the underscore _, the
>   lowercase and uppercase Latin letters, and other characters) and digits, which designates
>   one or more entities as described in 6.2.1 [..]

and, in §6.2.1, *Scopes of identifiers*

> An identifier can denote an object; a function; a tag or a member of a structure, union, or
>   enumeration; a typedef name; a label name; a macro name; or a macro parameter.

So, an array element is *not* an identifier.